# Angularjs and Jasmine: Testing a controller with a service making ajax call

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am very new to testing javascript. My application is using angularjs. I am using jasmine as a testing framework.

Here is the controller I am testing:

```
angular.module('logonController', ["ngval", "accountFactory"])
    .controller("logonController", function logOnController(accountFactory, $scope, $window) {
        $scope.hasServerError = false;
        $scope.Logon = function () {
            accountFactory.Logon($scope.data.LogOnModel)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $window.location.href = "/";
                },
                function (data) {
                    $scope.hasServerError = true;

                });
        }

    })
```

where accountFactory.Logon is making a Post request to the server.

What I want to test is when calling `accountFactory.Logon`:

1. On success - window.location.href is called
2. On error `$scope.hasServerError` is set to true

So far I have managed to do this:

```
"use strict";

describe("Logon Controller", function () {

    var $scope, $location, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $controller, $window, createController;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module("logonController");
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $location = $injector.get("$location");
        $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
        $controller = $injector.get("$controller");
        $window = $injector.get("$window");
    }));

    beforeEach(function () {
        createController = function () {
            return $controller("logonController", {
                "$scope": $scope,
            });
        };

        $scope.data = {
            LogOnModel: { username: "user", password: "pass" }
        };

        $window = { location: { href: jasmine.createSpy() } };
    });

    it("should redirect on successfull login", function () {
        var controller = createController();

        $httpBackend.whenPOST("/Account/Logon").respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
            return [200, {}, {}];
        });

        $scope.Logon();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($window.location.href).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

My idea is to create a spy on $window.location.href and only check if it is called. But I am getting

> Expected spy unknown to have been called.

As I said I am very new to testing javascript, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a spy:

```
spyOn($window, 'location.href').andCallThrough();
```

But on a bigger note though, you shouldnt be testing the functionality of your service in the controller test.

Answer (score 3):

## Sten Muchow's Answer is wrong in several aspects:

1. you can't specify a compound property name ("location.href") as 2nd parameter to spyOn. You have to give a real property name.
2. And even if you would do the spyOn correctly, andCallThrough() would still raise an exception, as $window.location.href is not a function which could be called through.

But he is still right in saying that you should not intermingle your controller test with the service test.

## To answer the question:

The reason, that your expectation is not met (that even the spy still exists*) is, that you're doing the $window.location.href assignment inside a promise's then() function. That means, it will be executed asynchronously, namely AFTER your expect() call. To go around this, you would need to make your test work asynchronously (for how to do this I would like to advise you to the Jasmine documentation: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html).

* In accountFactory.Logon, by doing `$window.location.href =` (i.e. assignment) you will effectively overwrite your spy.

## Even better solution:

Instead of manipulating `$window.location.href`, you should use `$location.url()`.

`$location` is an Angular core service. You will benefit from the integration within the Angular application lifecycle (i.e. watchers will be automatically processed when the url changes) + it is seamlessly integrated with existing HTML5 APIs like History API: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Then, you can spy on $location.url() as you would have spied on $window.location.href (if it had been a function).